# Why if I'm placing a lookbehind constraint on the capturing group, does it ensure compliance but also capture what is prior to the given constraint?

Tags: python, regex

Regex pattern in Python not capturing the correct substring, giving unexpected output

```py
import re

#example
input_text = "It is close to that place, the NY hospital was the place where I was born, the truth is that's all I know, and it happened in November of the year 2000."

#regex pattern
# partner_match = re.search(r"(?:(?:[^.,;\n]+)(?<=\s)|^)\s*(.+?)\s*(?:was|would be|is)\s*the\s*(?:place|side)", input_text, flags = re.IGNORECASE) # here I tried using the negation operator [^...] but it doesn't work
partner_match = re.search(r"(?:(?:\.|,|;|\n)(?<=\s)|^)\s*(.+?)\s*(?:was|would be|is)\s*the\s*(?:place|side)", input_text, flags=re.IGNORECASE)

#here print captured string
if partner_match: print(partner_match.group(1))
```

Why instead of giving me only this output :

```
the NY hospital
```

It incorrectly gives me all this string:

```
It is close to that place, the NY hospital
```

What should I fix in my regex capture restrictions?

Comment: I think it's using the `^` alternative instead of `(?:\.|,|;|\n)(?<=\s)`, so the lookbehind is ignored.

Comment: Here, the first part of the regex is a non-capturing group (?:\.|,|;|\n) followed by a positive lookbehind (?<=\s)

Comment: @Barmar mmm.... I tried something like this in the regex pattern of the commented line in the code of the question, however it continues capturing the part before the comma, point, etc...

Comment: It doesn't matter what you put in the first alternative, because the second alternative matches and it uses that.

Comment: @NonameNoSurname It is not a capturing group because that part before the capturing group should not be captured, however it must meet the condition that it starts capturing only if it is at the beginning of the string, or if there are any of the symbols indicated in the string. pattern (?:\.|,|;)

Comment: And in this case, it matches at the beginning of the string.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to say that if it can match at both the beginning or after the symbols, it should prefer the second match.

Comment: @Barmar I understand the logic of what you mean, but now I don't know how to approach the pattern structure, that is, I need it to capture only if it starts at the beginning of the string or if it is preceded by any of those punctuation marks, and always between sign and capturing group can optionally be whitespace \s*

Comment: You want it to capture if it starts at the beginning of the string. That's what it's doing, why is it wrong? Maybe you need to specify that the captured group can't contain any punctuation marks?

Comment: Change `(.+?)` to `([^,.;\n]+?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As explained in the comments, the regex engine will initially attempt a match at the beginning of the string. After failing to match `(?:\.|,|;|\n)(?<=\s)` at that location it attempts to match `^` and succeeds. It therefore will make no further attempts to match `(?:\.|,|;|\n)(?<=\s)`, hence the undesired result.

---

As an aside, note that `(?:\.|,|;|\n)(?<=\s)` is a faulty construct as it can only match a newline (`\n`), never a period, comma or semicolon. It reads, "match a period, comma, semicolon or newline, provided the character following is preceded by a whitespace character", but of course the character that precedes the character that follows X is X itself. Here the newline is the only character of the four that is a whitespace character.

Another problem is that by using `\s*` rather than `\s+` the string `"wasthesize"` (for example) is matched by the regular expression, `\s*(?:was|would be|is)\s*the\s*(?:place|side)`, which I assume is an undesirable behaviour.

Note that `(?:\.|,|;|\n)` can be expressed more compactly as a character class: `[.,;\n]`.

---

I assume the problem is to match a substring that begins after a space following a period, comma, semicolon or whitespace, and continues until it is followed by  " was the place", " was the side", " would be the place", " would be the side", " is the place" or " is the side".

In the event that the string contains more than one space that is preceded by a period, comma, semicolon or whitespace, it must be decided which identifies the beginning of the matched string. I have assumed it is the last such pairing that meets all the requirements.

---

You therefore may attempt to match the following regular expression.

```
[.,;\n] (.+) +(?:was|would be|is) +the +(?:place|side)
```

where the desired result would be contained in capture group 1.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/QX9XKy/1)

---

One may instead use a *positive lookbehind* and a *positive lookahead* to simply match (but not capture) the desired string.

```
(?<=[.,;\n] ).+(?= +(?:was|would be|is) +the +(?:place|side))
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/BfajlP/1)